# SQL ENUM vs foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just found `SET` and `ENUM` existed for SQL and am hence intrigued to use `ENUM` to replace 1:N where `ENUM` simply lists a few properties an object could have. Is it better to have a foreign key for this or model with `ENUM` for instance?

`Vehicle type -> ENUM('BIKE','POGO STICK','SUBMARINE','STAR DESTROYER')`

One benefit I see of having a property table is probably when you add a new property you only have to `INSERT` it to the property table whereas for `ENUM` you would have to run `ALTER` table? On the other hand it eliminates one join for DB lookups...?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-enum-vs-integer-types

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300376/which-is-reasonable-to-use-for-a-field-that-appears-in-three-tables-an-enum-or/43389718#43389718