# Altering an Enum field using Alembic

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

How can I add an element to an Enum field in an alembic migration when using a version of PostgreSQL older than 9.1 (which adds the ALTER TYPE for enums)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771543/postgresql-updating-an-enum-type) SO question explains the direct process, but I'm not quite sure how best to translate that using alembic.

This is what I have:

```
new_type = sa.Enum('nonexistent_executable', 'output_limit_exceeded',
                   'signal', 'success', 'timed_out', name='status')
old_type = sa.Enum('nonexistent_executable', 'signal', 'success', 'timed_out',
                   name='status')
tcr = sa.sql.table('testcaseresult',
                   sa.Column('status', new_type, nullable=False))


def upgrade():
    op.alter_column('testcaseresult', u'status', type_=new_type,
                    existing_type=old_type)


def downgrade():
    op.execute(tcr.update().where(tcr.c.status==u'output_limit_exceeded')
               .values(status='timed_out'))
    op.alter_column('testcaseresult', u'status', type_=old_type,
                    existing_type=new_type)
```

The above unfortunately only produces `ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status TYPE status` upon upgrade, which essentially does nothing.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I decided to try to follow the [postgres approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771543/postgresql-updating-an-enum-type) as directly as possible and came up with the following migration.

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

old_options = ('nonexistent_executable', 'signal', 'success', 'timed_out')
new_options = sorted(old_options + ('output_limit_exceeded',))

old_type = sa.Enum(*old_options, name='status')
new_type = sa.Enum(*new_options, name='status')
tmp_type = sa.Enum(*new_options, name='_status')

tcr = sa.sql.table('testcaseresult',
                   sa.Column('status', new_type, nullable=False))


def upgrade():
    # Create a tempoary "_status" type, convert and drop the "old" type
    tmp_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status TYPE _status'
               ' USING status::text::_status')
    old_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    # Create and convert to the "new" status type
    new_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status TYPE status'
               ' USING status::text::status')
    tmp_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)


def downgrade():
    # Convert 'output_limit_exceeded' status into 'timed_out'
    op.execute(tcr.update().where(tcr.c.status==u'output_limit_exceeded')
               .values(status='timed_out'))
    # Create a tempoary "_status" type, convert and drop the "new" type
    tmp_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status TYPE _status'
               ' USING status::text::_status')
    new_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    # Create and convert to the "old" status type
    old_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status TYPE status'
               ' USING status::text::status')
    tmp_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
```

It appears that alembic has no direct support for the `USING` statement in its `alter_table` method.

Comment: Works with alembic 0.7 and Postgres 9.4. PITA having to do it this way. Definitely hope I don't have to make any more adjustments to my ENUMs!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16821396/176978? On Postgres 9.4 you should be able to do it much more simply.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately I was dropping rather than adding which there doesn't seem to be any support for yet, [even in 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertype.html).

Comment: `ADD VALUE` has been around since [9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertype.html). However, even in 9.4, the operation [cannot be done inside a transaction block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertype.html#AEN70711) and all alembic migrations happen in transactions.

Comment: just in case someone was wondering: No transaction support for `ADD VALUE` in [PostgreSQL 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altertype.html) and AFAIK no plans to implement that in version 11.

Answer (score 35):

This runs without problems:

```
from alembic import op

def upgrade():
    op.execute("ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE 'new_value'")

def downgrade():
    ...
```

[Reference](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issues/123/a-way-to-run-non-transactional-ddl)

Comment: > when using a version of PostgreSQL older than 9.1

Comment: The most recent versions of Alembic provide the [autocommit_block](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.migration.MigrationContext.autocommit_block) context manager, which has been implemented for this exact use-case (see the link for details, an example, and limitations)

Comment: Note that a parallel `downgrade()` method doesn't exist since [postgres doesn't offer simple support for dropping a value from an existing enum, only adding values to one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812436/625840). So a downgrade would look more like @bboe 's answer that involves creating a temporary type and casting.

Comment: **Warning:** You probably shouldn't execute a `COMMIT` inside your upgrade. By default, Alembic use one transaction **per upgrade command, not per version**. Executing a commit will end the transaction and every following upgrade() executed - in case of multiple new versions - will be without a transaction (well, technically, with the autocommit mode, the SQL statement will form a single transaction on its own), perhaps even fail, like with a LOCK TABLE.

Answer (score 31):

I used a bit simpler approach with less steps than the accepted answer, which I based this on. In this example I will pretend the enum in question is called 'status_enum', because in the accepted answer the use of 'status' for both the column and enum confused me.

```
from alembic import op 
import sqlalchemy as sa

name = 'status_enum'
tmp_name = 'tmp_' + name

old_options = ('nonexistent_executable', 'signal', 'success', 'timed_out')
new_options = sorted(old_options + ('output_limit_exceeded',))

new_type = sa.Enum(*new_options, name=name)
old_type = sa.Enum(*old_options, name=name)

tcr = sa.sql.table('testcaseresult',
                   sa.Column('status', new_type, nullable=False))

def upgrade():
    op.execute('ALTER TYPE ' + name + ' RENAME TO ' + tmp_name)

    new_type.create(op.get_bind())
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status ' +
               'TYPE ' + name + ' USING status::text::' + name)
    op.execute('DROP TYPE ' + tmp_name)


def downgrade():
    # Convert 'output_limit_exceeded' status into 'timed_out'                                                                                                                      
    op.execute(tcr.update().where(tcr.c.status=='output_limit_exceeded')
               .values(status='timed_out'))

    op.execute('ALTER TYPE ' + name + ' RENAME TO ' + tmp_name)

    old_type.create(op.get_bind())
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE testcaseresult ALTER COLUMN status ' +
               'TYPE ' + name + ' USING status::text::' + name)
    op.execute('DROP TYPE ' + tmp_name)
```

Comment: Hi @JelteF, I used your approach but it throws an error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "category_type" does not exist` my column name is `caterory_types' and enum name is `CATEGORY_TYPE` which is an OrderedDict , I am using Postgres 10.4 and alembic 0.9.9

Comment: This worked for me, the original accepted answer gave an empty type.

Answer (score 13):

As of Postgres 9.1 adding a new value to an enum can be done with the [`ALTER TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertype.html) statement. This is complicated by the fact that [it cannot be done in a transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertype.html#AEN63173). However this can be worked around by committing alembic's transaction [see here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issue/123/a-way-to-run-non-transactional-ddl).

I actually had problems using the older, more verbose, solution because Postgres could not automatically convert the default for the column.

Comment: alembic uses github for issue tracking now: [A way to run non-transactional DDL commands #123](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/123)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue trying to migrate a column type to another. I use the following requirements:

```
Alembic==0.9.4
SQLAlchemy==1.1.12
```

You can provide the argument `postgresql_using` as a kwarg of `alembic.op.alter_column`.

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as types

op.alter_column(
    table_name='my_table',
    column_name='my_column',
    type_=types.NewType,
    # allows to use postgresql USING
    postgresql_using="my_column::PostgesEquivalentOfNewType",
)
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: In case of a Postgres ENUMs we might want to use a cast (OLD_TYPE -> text -> NEW_TYPE): `postgresql_using="my_column::text::PostgesEquivalentOfNewType"` In case of this question it's actually a must have. However, this answer is great, saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Ran into this issue and this answer works great and is far less... complicated than other answers, seriously thanks

Answer (score 10):

First alter your column type to VARCHAR().

Then drop your type and create new type with new fields.

and finally alter your column type to your new created type.

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute(
        '''
        ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_enum_column TYPE VARCHAR(255);

        DROP TYPE IF EXISTS your_enum_type;

        CREATE TYPE your_enum_type AS ENUM 
            ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4');

        ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_enum_column TYPE your_enum_type 
            USING (your_enum_column::your_enum_type);
        '''
    )


def downgrade():
    op.execute(
        '''
        ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_enum_column TYPE VARCHAR(255);

        DROP TYPE IF EXISTS your_enum_type;

        CREATE TYPE your_enum_type AS ENUM 
            ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

        ALTER TABLE your_table ALTER COLUMN your_enum_column TYPE your_enum_type 
            USING (your_enum_column::your_enum_type);
        '''
    )
```

Comment: Disgusting and I love it

Answer (score 4):

In straight SQL, this would work for Postgres, if the order of the things in your enum doesn't need to be exactly as above:

```
ALTER TYPE status ADD value 'output_limit_exceeded' after 'timed_out';
```

Comment: That support was added in PostgreSQL 9.1. I'll update the question to be more specific (I wish I was using 9.1).

Comment: The whole point of using Alembic and SQLAlchemy is to avoid writing pure SQL unless you have to. And ideally get migration scripts generated automatically based on SQLAlchemy models.

Comment: The main problem with this is that `ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE ...` can't be used within a transaction.

Comment: This question is about migrate, so how to remove an added value in ENUM? How about the `downgrade`

Comment: @TienHoang the hard way, creating a new type, and swapping it with the old one, postgres does not support removing a value from an existing enum  =/

Answer (score 4):

There are already many working answers here, but I would like to add that there is a possibility to automate adding and removing values from enum using my [alembic-postgresql-enum](https://pypi.org/project/alembic-postgresql-enum/) library.

Installation:

```
pip install alembic-postgresql-enum
```

Add import to env.py

```py
import alembic_postgresql_enum
```

the following migration will be generated when a change is made to enum:

```py
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.sync_enum_values('public', 'status', ['signal', 'output_limit_exceeded', 'success', 'timed_out'], 
                        [('testcaseresult', 'status')],
                        enum_values_to_rename=[])
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.sync_enum_values('public', 'status', ['signal', 'success', 'timed_out'], 
                        [('testcaseresult', 'status')],
                        enum_values_to_rename=[])
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Answer (score 3):

Found another handy method

```
op.execute('ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE new_value')
op.execute('ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE new_value BEFORE old_value')
op.execute('ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE new_value AFTER old_value')
```

Answer (score 3):

This method can be used to update an Enum:

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute("ALTER TYPE categorytype RENAME VALUE 'EXAMPLE_A' TO 'EXAMPLE_B'")


def downgrade():
    op.execute("ALTER TYPE categorytype RENAME VALUE 'EXAMPLE_B' TO 'EXAMPLE_A'")
```

Answer (score 3):

This approach is similar to [the accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14845740/8445442), but with minor differences:

1. it uses `op.batch_alter_table` instead of `op.execute('ALTER TABLE')`, so this solution works in both PostgreSQL and SQLite: SQLite doesn't supports `ALTER TABLE` but alembic provides a support for it with `op.batch_alter_table`
2. it doesn't uses raw SQL

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# Describing of enum
enum_name = "status"
temp_enum_name = f"temp_{enum_name}"
old_values = ("nonexistent_executable", "signal", "success", "timed_out")
new_values = ("output_limit_exceeded", *old_values)
downgrade_to = ("output_limit_exceeded", "timed_out") # on downgrade convert [0] to [1]
old_type = sa.Enum(*old_values, name=enum_name)
new_type = sa.Enum(*new_values, name=enum_name)
temp_type = sa.Enum(*new_values, name=temp_enum_name)

# Describing of table
table_name = "testcaseresult"
column_name = "status"
temp_table = sa.sql.table(
    table_name,
    sa.Column(
        column_name,
        new_type,
        nullable=False
    )
)


def upgrade():
    # temp type to use instead of old one
    temp_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)

    # changing of column type from old enum to new one.
    # SQLite will create temp table for this
    with op.batch_alter_table(table_name) as batch_op:
        batch_op.alter_column(
            column_name,
            existing_type=old_type,
            type_=temp_type,
            existing_nullable=False,
            postgresql_using=f"{column_name}::text::{temp_enum_name}"
        )

    # remove old enum, create new enum
    old_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    new_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)

    # changing of column type from temp enum to new one.
    # SQLite will create temp table for this
    with op.batch_alter_table(table_name) as batch_op:
        batch_op.alter_column(
            column_name,
            existing_type=temp_type,
            type_=new_type,
            existing_nullable=False,
            postgresql_using=f"{column_name}::text::{enum_name}"
        )

    # remove temp enum
    temp_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)


def downgrade():
    # old enum don't have new value anymore.
    # before downgrading from new enum to old one,
    # we should replace new value from new enum with
    # somewhat of old values from old enum
    op.execute(
        temp_table
        .update()
        .where(
            temp_table.c.status == downgrade_to[0]
        )
        .values(
            status=downgrade_to[1]
        )
    )

    temp_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)

    with op.batch_alter_table(table_name) as batch_op:
        batch_op.alter_column(
            column_name,
            existing_type=new_type,
            type_=temp_type,
            existing_nullable=False,
            postgresql_using=f"{column_name}::text::{temp_enum_name}"
        )

    new_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
    old_type.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)

    with op.batch_alter_table(table_name) as batch_op:
        batch_op.alter_column(
            column_name,
            existing_type=temp_type,
            type_=old_type,
            existing_nullable=False,
            postgresql_using=f"{column_name}::text::{enum_name}"
        )

    temp_type.drop(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=False)
```

From the accepted solution:

> It appears that alembic has no direct support for the USING statement in its alter_table method.

For now alembic supports `USING` statement in its `alter_table` method.

Answer (score 3):

There's the solution for PostgreSQL that allows you to do it with one `alter_column` method, so you don't need to create tmp type (real world example of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615354/15513881)):

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'c39019503835'
down_revision = '02795fd4329f'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

old_type = sa.Enum('UPCOMING', 'ACTIVE', 'FINISHED', 'POSTPONED', 'CANCELLED', name='gamestatus')
new_type = sa.Enum('UPCOMING', 'ACTIVE', 'FINISHED', 'READY_FOR_SETTLE', 'CANCELLED', name='gamestatus')


def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column(
        'games',
        'status',
        existing_type=old_type,
        type_=new_type,
        postgresql_using='status::text::gamestatus',
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column(
        'games',
        'status',
        existing_type=new_type,
        type_=old_type,
        postgresql_using='status::text::gamestatus',
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Comment: Downvoted because the answer lacks an explanation. "2023 solution" is unclear: please edit your answer to explain why this solution is better than the existing ones.

Comment: @bfontaine ok now?

Comment: what’s the advantage of this method versus, for example, [that one from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45615354/735926)?

Comment: @bfontaine updated. it's not a new solution, but it extends the existing one

Answer (score 1):

I needed to move data while migrating types, including deleting some old types, so I figured I'd write up a more general way of doing this based on the (awesome) accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14845740/629272). Hopefully this helps someone else in the same boat!

```
# This migration will move data from one column to two others based on the type
# for a given row, and modify the type of each row.
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

revision = '000000000001'
down_revision = '000000000000'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

# This set of options makes up the old type.
example_types_old = (
    'EXAMPLE_A',
    'EXAMPLE_B',
    'EXAMPLE_C',
)
example_type_enum_old = postgresql.ENUM(*example_types_old, name='exampletype')

# This set of options makes up the new type.
example_types_new = (
    'EXAMPLE_C',
    'EXAMPLE_D',
    'EXAMPLE_E',
)
example_type_enum_new = postgresql.ENUM(*example_types_new, name='exampletype')

# This set of options includes everything from the old and new types.
example_types_tmp = set(example_types_old + example_types_new)
example_type_enum_tmp = postgresql.ENUM(*example_types_tmp, name='_exampletype')

# This is a table view from which we can select and update as necessary. This
# only needs to include the relevant columns which are in either the old or new
# version of the table.
examples_view = sa.Table(
    # Use the name of the actual table so it is modified in the upgrade and
    # downgrade.
    'examples',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    # Use the _tmp type so all types are usable.
    sa.Column('example_type', example_type_enum_tmp),
    # This is a column from which the data will be migrated, after which the
    # column will be removed.
    sa.Column('example_old_column', sa.Integer),
    # This is a column to which data from the old column will be added if the
    # type is EXAMPLE_A.
    sa.Column('example_new_column_a', sa.Integer),
    # This is a column to which data from the old column will be added if the
    # type is EXAMPLE_B.
    sa.Column('example_new_column_b', sa.Integer),
)


def upgrade():
    connection = op.get_bind()

    # Add the new column to which data will be migrated.
    example_new_column_a = sa.Column(
        'example_new_column_a',
        sa.Integer,
        nullable=True
    )
    op.add_column('examples', example_new_column_a)

    # Add the new column to which data will be migrated.
    example_new_column_b = sa.Column(
        'example_new_column_b',
        sa.Integer,
        nullable=True
    )
    op.add_column('examples', example_new_column_b)

    # Create the temporary enum and change the example_type column to use the
    # temporary enum.
    # The USING statement automatically maps the old enum to the temporary one.
    example_type_enum_tmp.create(connection, checkfirst=False)
    # Change to the temporary type and map from the old type to the temporary
    # one.
    op.execute('''
        ALTER TABLE examples
            ALTER COLUMN example_type
                TYPE _exampletype
                USING example_type::text::_exampletype
    ''')

    # Move data from example_old_column to example_new_column_a and change its
    # type to EXAMPLE_D if the type is EXAMPLE_A.
    connection.execute(
        examples_view.update().where(
            examples_view.c.example_type == 'EXAMPLE_A'
        ).values(
            example_type='EXAMPLE_D',
            example_new_column_a=examples_view.c.example_old_column,
        )
    )

    # Move data from example_old_column to example_new_column_b and change its
    # type to EXAMPLE_E if the type is EXAMPLE_B.
    connection.execute(
        examples_view.update().where(
            examples_view.c.example_type == 'EXAMPLE_B'
        ).values(
            example_type='EXAMPLE_E',
            example_new_column_b=examples_view.c.example_old_column,
        )
    )

    # Move any remaining data from example_old_column to example_new_column_a
    # and keep its type as EXAMPLE_C.
    connection.execute(
        examples_view.update().where(
            examples_view.c.example_type == 'EXAMPLE_C'
        ).values(
            example_type='EXAMPLE_C',
            example_new_column_a=examples_view.c.example_old_column,
        )
    )

    # Delete the old enum now that the data with the old types have been moved.
    example_type_enum_old.drop(connection, checkfirst=False)

    # Create the new enum and change the example_type column to use the new
    # enum.
    # The USING statement automatically maps the temporary enum to the new one.
    example_type_enum_new.create(connection, checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('''
        ALTER TABLE examples
            ALTER COLUMN example_type
                TYPE exampletype
                USING example_type::text::exampletype
    ''')

    # Delete the temporary enum.
    example_type_enum_tmp.drop(connection, checkfirst=False)

    # Remove the old column.
    op.drop_column('examples', 'example_old_column')


# The downgrade just performs the opposite of all the upgrade operations but in
# reverse.
def downgrade():
    connection = op.get_bind()

    example_old_column = sa.Column(
        'example_old_column',
        sa.Integer,
        nullable=True
    )
    op.add_column('examples', example_old_column)

    example_type_enum_tmp.create(connection, checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('''
        ALTER TABLE examples
            ALTER COLUMN example_type
                TYPE _exampletype
                USING example_type::text::_exampletype
    ''')

    connection.execute(
        examples_view.update().where(
            examples_view.c.example_type == 'EXAMPLE_C'
        ).values(
            example_type='EXAMPLE_C',
            example_old_column=examples_view.c.example_new_column_b,
        )
    )

    connection.execute(
        examples_view.update().where(
            examples_view.c.example_type == 'EXAMPLE_E'
        ).values(
            example_type='EXAMPLE_B',
            example_old_column=examples_view.c.example_new_column_b,
        )
    )

    connection.execute(
        examples_view.update().where(
            examples_view.c.example_type == 'EXAMPLE_D'
        ).values(
            example_type='EXAMPLE_A',
            example_old_column=examples_view.c.example_new_column_a,
        )
    )

    example_type_enum_old.create(connection, checkfirst=False)
    op.execute('''
        ALTER TABLE examples
            ALTER COLUMN example_type
                TYPE exampletype
                USING example_type::text::exampletype
    ''')

    example_type_enum_tmp.drop(connection, checkfirst=False)

    op.drop_column('examples', 'example_new_column_b')
    op.drop_column('examples', 'example_new_column_a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I got conversion errors and problems with default values, I wrote an even more generalised answer based on the accepted one:

```
def replace_enum_values(
        name: str,
        old: [str],
        new: [str],
        modify: [(str, str, str)]
):
    """
    Replaces an enum's list of values.

    Args:
        name: Name of the enum
        new: New list of values
        old: Old list of values
        modify: List of tuples of table name
        and column to modify (which actively use the enum).
        Assumes each column has a default val.
    """
    connection = op.get_bind()

    tmp_name = "{}_tmp".format(name)

    # Rename old type
    op.execute(
        "ALTER TYPE {} RENAME TO {};"
        .format(name, tmp_name)
    )

    # Create new type
    lsl = sa.Enum(*new, name=name)
    lsl.create(connection)

    # Replace all usages
    for (table, column) in modify:
        # Get default to re-set later
        default_typed = connection.execute(
            "SELECT column_default "
            "FROM information_schema.columns "
            "WHERE table_name='{table}' "
            "AND column_name='{column}';"
            .format(table=table, column=column)
        ).first()[0]  # type: str

        # Is bracketed already
        default = default_typed[:default_typed.index("::")]

        # Set all now invalid values to default
        connection.execute(
            "UPDATE {table} "
            "SET {column}={default} "
            "WHERE {column} NOT IN {allowed};"
            .format(
                table=table,
                column=column,
                # Invalid: What isn't contained in both new and old
                # Can't just remove what's not in new because we get
                # a type error
                allowed=tuple(set(old).intersection(set(new))),
                default=default
            )
        )

        op.execute(
            "ALTER TABLE {table} "
            # Default needs to be dropped first
            "ALTER COLUMN {column} DROP DEFAULT,"
            # Replace the tpye
            "ALTER COLUMN {column} TYPE {enum_name} USING {column}::text::{enum_name},"
            # Reset default
            "ALTER COLUMN {column} SET DEFAULT {default};"
            .format(
                table=table,
                column=column,
                enum_name=name,
                default=default
            )
        )

    # Remove old type
    op.execute("DROP TYPE {};".format(tmp_name))
```

This can be called from upgrade / downgrade as such:

```
replace_enum_values(
    name='enum_name',
    new=["A", "B"],
    old=["A", "C"],
    modify=[('some_table', 'some_column')]
)
```

All invalidated values will be set to server_default.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is easy to understand and works really well for both upgrade and downgrade. I've written this answer in more detailed manner.

Let's say our `enum_type` looks like this:

```
enum_type = ('some_value_1', 'some_value_2')
```

I want to alter `enum_type` by adding a new enum, so that it becomes like this:

```
enum_type = ('some_value_1', 'some_value_2', 'new_value')
```

This can be done in this way:

```py
from alembic import op


def upgrade():
    op.execute("COMMIT")
    op.execute("ALTER TYPE enum_type ADD VALUE 'new_value'")


def downgrade():
    # Drop 'new_value' from enum_type
    op.execute("ALTER TYPE enum_type RENAME TO enum_type_tmp")

    op.execute("CREATE TYPE enum_type AS ENUM('some_value_1', 'some_value_1')")

    op.execute("DROP TYPE enum_type_tmp")
```

**NOTE: During downgrade, if you're using `enum_type` in a table then you can modify the downgrade method as mentioned below:**

```py
def downgrade():
    # Drop 'new_value' from enum_type
    op.execute("UPDATE table_name"
               " SET column_name_using_enum_type_value = NULL"
               " WHERE column_name_using_enum_type_value = 'new_value'")    

    op.execute("ALTER TYPE enum_type RENAME TO enum_type_tmp")

    op.execute("CREATE TYPE enum_type AS ENUM('some_value_1', 'some_value_1')")

    op.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name"
               " ALTER COLUMN column_name_using_enum_type_value TYPE enum_type"
               " USING column_name_using_enum_type_value::text::enum_type")

    op.execute("DROP TYPE enum_type_tmp")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Observation

In order to alleviate the pain when migrating, I **always use non-native enums even with PostgreSQL**.

Non-native enums are just strings with constraints, if you edit an enum, there are only three scenarios:

1. Rename enum values
2. Remove enum values
3. Add enum values.

For migrations, 2 & 3 are a pair. This is understandable: if you upgrade for adding, then you have to remove when downgrading and vice versa. So let's categorize them as two types.

### Implementation

If it's renaming, normally I'll break it into three steps:

1. Drop old constraints
2. Update the rows' old value to the new value
3. Create new constraints

In alembic, this is done by:

```py
def update_enum(
    table, column, enum_class_name, target_values, olds_to_remove, news_to_add
):
    op.drop_constraint(f"ck_{table}_{enum_class_name}", table)

    for sql in update_enum_sqls(table, column, olds_to_remove, news_to_add):
        op.execute(sql)

    op.create_check_constraint(
        enum_class_name, table, sa.sql.column(column).in_(target_values)
    )
```

Let's forget `update_enum_sqls` first and just use it as a SQL generator.

If it's removing, well there are still three steps:

1. Drop old constraints
2. Delete rows with the old value
3. Create new constraints

So basically only the `update_enum_sqls` might behave differently.

If it's adding, only two steps:

1. Drop old constraints
2. Create new constraints

Still, we can ignore the `update_enum_sqls`.

So how to implement it? Not that hard...

```py
def update_enum_sql(table, column, old_value, new_value):
    if new_value is not None:
        return f"UPDATE {table} SET {column} = '{new_value}' where {column} = '{old_value}'"
    else:
        return f"DELETE FROM {table} where {column} = '{old_value}'"


def update_enum_sqls(table, column, olds_to_remove, news_to_add):
    if len(olds_to_remove) != len(news_to_add):
        raise NotImplementedError
    return [
        update_enum_sql(table, column, old, new)
        for old, new in zip(olds_to_remove, news_to_add)
    ]
```

### Example

Since we prepared the ingredients, let's apply:

```py
def upgrade():
    # rename enum
    update_enum(
        "my_table",
        "my_enum",
        "myenumclassname",
        ["NEW", "ENUM", "VALUES"],
        ["OLD"],
        ["NEW"],
    )

    # add enum
    update_enum(
        "my_table",
        "my_enum",
        "myenumclassname",
        ["NEW", "ENUM", "VALUES"],
        [],
        [],
    )


def downgrade():
    # remove enum
    update_enum(
        "my_table",
        "my_enum",
        "myenumclassname",
        ["ENUM", "VALUES"],
        ["NEW"],
        [None],  # this will delete rows with "NEW", USE WITH CARE!!!
    )

    # edit enum
    update_enum(
        "my_table",
        "my_enum",
        "myenumclassname",
        ["OLD", "ENUM", "VALUES"],
        ["NEW"],
        ["OLD"],
    )
```

The code above can also be found on [gist](https://gist.github.com/kigawas/b19952e7c40b46566753684800a9ddea).