# How to write a down migration for Postgresql where up migration adds an enum value?

Tags: postgresql, enums, database-migration

I want to expand my enum type by adding a new enum value. This is pretty straightforward to do. I also keep all my SQL in migrations, and pair each up migration with a symmetric down migration that reverts the schema to the previous state.

However, reverse operation — removing a variant from enum — [is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811017/how-to-delete-an-enum-type-value-in-postgres).

What's the common method around this? I can see two options:

1. Write "up" migration with `if not exists` clause and do nothing in the "down" migration. I don't like this option because it violates the assumption that applying and reverting a migration leaves the schema in the same state as it was before.
2. Convert to a new enum type in "down" migration, as described in the question linked above — seems like an overkill for such a simple operation.

Comment: Another good example why enums are usually not such a good idea. This would be very easy if you used a standard lookup table with a foreign key. Removing the value would as simple as running a `DELETE` statement

Comment: Is "migration", in the context of this question, a technical term, or a word you use to describe a process which means something to you but not to me?

Comment: @eurotrash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point. However, for now I think that enums with a constant amount of variants that map 1-to-1 to enum variants in the application language fit my needs better than a foreign key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not migrate an `ENUM`. Your opinions and assessments are 100% correct.

> I don't like this option because it violates the assumption that applying and reverting a migration leaves the schema in the same state as it was before.

If that's a hangup, then the option is out of the picture. Because you're correct.

> seems like an overkill for such a simple operation.

That's because deleting a value from an `ENUM` is not a simple operation. So why would migrating an `ENUM` with more values, to one with fewer values be a simple operation?

Listen to the horse,

> *Another good example why enums are usually not such a good idea. This would be very easy if you used a standard lookup table with a foreign key. Removing the value would as simple as running a DELETE statement* – a_horse_with_no_name