# Postgres 15: Does adding value to enum acquires any sort of lock?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres (and using 15 due to platform limitation), and considering enum as column type.

In future, when I run `ALTER TYPE name ADD VALUE ...` to add value to enum, does it acquires any sort of lock?

If it does, what kind of lock it acquires? How long it keeps approximately?

Comment: You are aware that enum types are primarily intended for *static* sets of values? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25812436/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an `ExclusiveLock` on the enum until you commit the transaction that's running the `ALTER TYPE my_enum ADD VALUE`. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/sQvFwVTX)

```sql
create type my_enum as enum('first','second');
begin;
select relation::regclass,objid::regtype,locktype,mode from pg_locks;
```

| relation | objid | locktype | mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pg_locks | *null* | relation | AccessShareLock |
| *null* | *null* | virtualxid | ExclusiveLock |
| *null* | *null* | transactionid | ExclusiveLock |

```sql
alter type my_enum add value 'third' after 'second';
select relation::regclass,objid::regtype,locktype,mode from pg_locks;
```

| relation | objid | locktype | mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pg_locks | *null* | relation | AccessShareLock |
| *null* | *null* | virtualxid | ExclusiveLock |
| *null* | **my_enum** | object | ExclusiveLock |
| *null* | *null* | transactionid | ExclusiveLock |

What it does is block any other transaction from `alter`ing/`drop`ping the enum, so if your plan was to to keep adding and removing values from it a lot, it might be a bottleneck. Otherwise, during the `alter` everyone else can continue their work involving the type - in case you were worried the `alter` temporarily halts *all* operations using the `my_enum`, like writing/reading/comparing/creating new relations with it.