# Flask-Alembic error sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type does not exist

Tags: postgresql, flask, database-migration, alembic

I'm trying to automate upgrade of database for project written in Flask. I use alembic for Flask.

The problem is when I use several enums it always run the error on the second enum, I don't understand why and how to fix it.

File enums.py:

```
from enum import Enum

class A(Enum):
    i = 'i'
    a = 'a'

class B(Enum):
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'
```

Model that uses them:

```
from enums import A, B

class Test(db.Model):
    status_a = db.Column(db.Enum(A)) 
    status_b = db.Column(db.Enum(B))
```

Now I'm doing the upgrade:

```
from libs import alembic
alembic.revision()
alembic.upgrade()
```

It always catches the error on the second enum:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) type "b" does not exist
```

What to do? I found some solutions but I don't how to use them, and don't understand completely what's going.

Update: migration code:

```
def upgrade():
# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
op.add_column('Account', sa.Column('activity_status', sa.Enum('inactive1', 'active1', name='abd'), nullable=True))
op.drop_column('Account', 'valid_status')
# ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your migration?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I updated my question, thanks.

Comment: @minic I don't see migration for `Test` model. As I see you have problem with `Test` model but not with `Account`. Where is  `Test` model migration? By the way you don't have `primary_key`.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar It's the same. I just changed model's name but code is absolutely identical.

Comment: Did you generate a new migration after changes?

Comment: Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860817/6762200