# How do I manually generate an alembic migration script that updates an Enum column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Technologies I am using:

- python 3.6
- postgres 10.4
- flask
- flask_migrate
- flask_sqlalchemy

So far I have relied on the autogenerated migration scripts that result from calling `python app.py db migrate`. I then apply these migration scripts by calling `python app.py db upgrade`. However my most recent change involves modifying an Enum that I have used to create a column. Here is a simplified example of my enum:

```
class EventType(Enum):
    started = 1
    completed = 2
    aborted = 2
```

(Note the typo with the repeated value of 2.)
Here is what I am attempting to change the Enum to:

```
class EventType(Enum):
    started = 1
    completed = 2
    aborted = 3
    failed = 4
```

My changes were to fix the typo and to add a new value to the enum.

Here is the (simplified) model that makes use of that enum:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.Enum(EventType))
```

A call to `python app.py db migrate` did not detect any changes and I have read in the documentation that `alembic` (which is used under the hood in `flask_migrate`) does not automatically detect enum changes. [1](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845203) question from ~6 years ago seems to indicate there is a better way to handle this problem after Postgres 9.4

I am looking for the specific steps I need to take to either manually write my own migration script or to get `flask_migrate` to detect this change and generate the script for me. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information to help with answering this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here was my ultimate solution to my problem:

1) Generate a blank revision file with `python app.py db revision --message "new event types"`

2) Modify the new file by entering the following lines into the `upgrade()` method:

```
op.execute("COMMIT")
op.execute("ALTER TYPE eventtype ADD VALUE 'failed'")
```

3) Save and apply the usual way with `python app.py db upgrade`.

Notes:

- This does not deal with the typo value. From what I could tell Postgres does not store the python enum value anywhere and doesn't care what it is.
- This does not remove the values in the `downgrade()` method. I couldn't find a straightforward way to do that so I just ignored it. In my case I do not think it will matter if the downgrade does not remove those extra values.
- I learned the name of my type (`eventtype`) by reading through the migration file that initially created the table that included that type.