# After updating Enum with a new value, that value cannot be inserted with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I want to store organization data in PostgreSQL database using Enums. Since organization names sometimes change, I need to sometimes update the Enum values, and I want to automatize this using Python with `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2`. However after altering the Enum, new values cannot be inserted.

I suspect that this is due to internal `check()` method of `psycopg2`, since the database do accept the new value. Do you know a method to update the types known by `psycopg2`?

Here are my tests for this script:

```
class DbconTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.engine, self.meta = db.get_connection('test_user', 'test_pass', 'testdb')
        # Create test table, which will be deleted later
        self.test_table = Table('test_table', self.meta,
                                Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                                Column('type', Enum('number', 'text', 'image', name='type'), nullable=False),
                                Column('text', String(32)))
        self.meta.create_all()

    def test_add_enum_value(self):
        try:
            # Add new value to enum named 'type'
            db.add_enum_value(self.engine, 'type', 'object')
        except Exception as exp:
            self.assertTrue(False, msg=exp.__cause__)
        else:
            self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_bulk_copy(self):
        types = ['number', 'text', 'image', 'object']
        objects = [{'id': idx,
                    'type': types[idx % len(types)],
                    'text': 'random text to insert'} for idx in range(10000)]
        try:
            db.bulk_copy(self.engine, str(self.test_table.name), objects)
        except Exception as exp:
            self.assertTrue(False, msg=exp.__cause__)
        else:
            self.assertTrue(True)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.meta.drop_all()
```

And a little explanation: Basically I create a test table in a test db, and then extend an enum type with a new value. Then I try to insert a huge amount of data, with new value of the enum among them. I got the following error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input value for enum type: "object"
```

Comment: psycopg2 does not keep track of the enum values it knows. I suspect your test case fails because `test_add_enum_value` is not guaranteed to execute before `test_bulk_copy`.

Comment: I see, but if execution order varies from run to run, is some cases I would get green runs, however it fails on every run.

Comment: That's an incorrect assumption. If the execution order *is not guaranteed*, then the two functions *can* run in any order; they do not *have to* run in all possible orders. In order words, the order can be arbitrary but stable.

Comment: I have just realised that setUp and tearDown is run before EVERY test, until now I have thought that setUp is run once, then all tests in the testcase is run, and then tearDown is called. So basically the problem was, that a completely different table object was used to insert, not the one I thought.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue, and then I solved that with update the enum value from **PostgreSQL** directly following [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771543/adding-a-new-value-to-an-existing-enum-type/3275885#3275885), we can also follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771543/adding-a-new-value-to-an-existing-enum-type/7834949#7834949) to update enum on **PostgreSQL** directly.

Answer (score 0):

The enum value in the database should be updated (if you dont want to use migration etc), following sql code helps you

```
ALTER TYPE type ADD VALUE 'object';
```