# How to execute SQL command without a transaction block in Golang?

Tags: sql, go

**Problem**

```sql
Error running schema migration, err: cmd failed, cmd:
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" ALTER COLUMN kill_id TYPE VARCHAR(MAX)
err: pq: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN cannot run inside a transaction block
```

AWS Redshift does not support running the above ALTER COMMAND in an transaction block.

Does [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) supports running sql commands without a transaction block?

How to run raw sql commands without a transaction block in Golang?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149484/error-alter-type-add-cannot-run-inside-a-transaction-block

Comment: @LinPy not related. "ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" ALTER COLUMN kill_id TYPE VARCHAR(MAX)" command works in redshift. Need to do the same from golang. It can be done if run without a transaction.

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh add the code how are you running this

Comment: this is also not working ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" ALTER COLUMN kill_id TYPE VARCHAR(MAX)", redshift does not support ALTER COLUMN on all column types, i would have to create a new table and migrate the table :(

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava the code was something like this https://github.com/Clever/s3-to-redshift/blob/master/redshift/redshift.go#L347-L357

Comment: Issue seems to be you are using *sql.Tx; dont do that use sql.DB

Comment: Thanks, i tried that. But the issue is Redshift does not allow such ALTER commands. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101918/alter-column-data-type-in-amazon-redshift