# How add a new value to an enum in Liquibase?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to add a new value to an enumeration in Liquibase.
I was using:

```
<changeSet id="update_status_enum_type_add_expired" >
    <sql>ALTER TYPE status ADD VALUE 'Expired';</sql>
</changeSet>
```

But I get

> "ERROR: ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot run inside a transaction block"

Any idea how to work it out?

Comment: Try to specify `runInTransaction="false"` in the `changeSet`

Comment: works great, thx. I also found that solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376907/10218144 which works fine too, only more verbose. Would there be any concern if performing that update out of a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used as suggested in the comments:

```
<changeSet id="update_status_enum_type_add_expired" author="Team" runInTransaction="false">
    <sql>ALTER TYPE job_status ADD VALUE 'Expired';</sql>
</changeSet>
```